# In-place function with return value

Tags: c++, c++11, in-place

I have a function that has a similar behavior of this:

```
void process(const T& input,T& output){
    if(&input==&output){
        //Alter output directly
    }
    else{
        output=input; //Deep Copy
        //Alter output
    }
}
```

**Use case 1:**

```
T i;
//fill i
T o;
process(i,o);
```

**Use case 2:**

```
T io;
//fill io
process(io,io);
```

---

I want to change this function deceleration to be more readable:

```
T process(const T& input){
   //What to do here?
}
```

**Use case 1:**

```
T i;
//fill i
auto o = process(i);
```

**Use case 2:**

```
T io;
//fill io
io=process(io);
```

**Question:** How can I imitate the previous methodology of dealing with in-place cases? How should I implement it? I need to avoid deep copying when it is the same object.

Comment: Why not have two functions? The function is not aware of where you store the result.

Comment: What should `auto o = process(i)` do if it does not make a deep copy? `o` should be a reference to `i`?

Comment: @Holt it must do deep copy. &i != &o

Comment: @Benoit Sorry but did not get you

Comment: @Holt mmmm no it is not.. One should fill 'i' then call the 'process' function to get 'o' output

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, you want two use cases that do unrelated things. Therefore I think you need two functions called for instance `process_in_place` and `process_copy`

Comment: @Benoit.. I see. However, it was possible when the output was a reference variable. So, I thought there may be some solution with output as return value. Thanks

Comment: return `void` and just use `process(o)` in both cases. Start with `o = i;` if requred

Comment: @M.M You mean I should provide just in-place version of the function the it is the user responsibility to make a copy if needed. It solves the problem but still not so readable IMO. Thanks